# take div out of parent and add to parent above

Tags: jquery

I have this html:

```
<div class="div1">
    one
    <div class="div2">
        two
        <div class="div3">
            three
        </div> <!-- /.div3 -->
    </div> <!-- /.div2 -->
</div> <!-- /.div1 -->
```

I want to take `div3` out of `div2` so that `div1` becomes its parent.

I tried like so, but this just added the content to `div1` and not the whole div:

```
$('.div3').unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elem = $('.div3').detach();
elem.prependTo('.div1');
```

Notice that I prepended (instead of just appending) so you can actually notice a difference.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3wLwnb2/)

More info about [detach()](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Try to use [`.wrap(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) at this context,</strike>

```
$('.div2').wrap(".div3");
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gdddjgp0/)

Inspect the elements in the demo to understand what is going on.

---

Sorry misunderstood the question, Use [`.prepend(element)`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) at this context

```
$('.div1').prepend($(".div3"));
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gdddjgp0/1/)